# if statement in a mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I'm getting a

> `continue` must be inside a loop

which I recognize as a syntax error on my part because it should be fixed.

Will fixing this to retain this logic in an if statement work with the mapping?

```
sales = data.map(function(d) { 
    if (isNaN(+d.BookingID) == false && isNaN(+d["Total Paid"]) == false) {
        return [+d.BookingID,   +d["Total Paid"]]; 
    } else {
        continue;
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `continue`. `.map()` will iterate over *all* items in `data`.

Comment: I want the opposite behavior of continue in that case. If the row I am mapping has either BookingID and Total Paid as NaN after converting to numeric, I want to skip those.

Comment: If you only want to return data that matches a condition use a [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), not `.map`.

Comment: `.map()` executes a function on each data point in the array and sets that data point to whatever is returned from the callback function. Are you looking for `.filter()` instead?

Comment: `.filter(/* if condition */).map(/* return expression */)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you cannot "continue" from within a `map` callback to skip elements. You need to use `filter`. To avoid referencing the fields twice, once in the filter, and once in the map, I'd filter afterwards:

```
sales = data
  .map(d => [+d["bookingId"], +d["Total Paid"]])
  .filter(([id, total]) => !isNaN(id) && !isNaN(total));
```

or, to make it easier in case you later want to include additional values in the array:

```
sales = data
  .map(d => [+d["bookingId"], +d["Total Paid"]])
  .filter(results => results.every(not(isNaN)));
```

where

```
function not(fn) { return x => !fn(x); }
```

or

```
function allNotNaN(a) { return a.every(not(isNaN)); }
```

and the, using parameter destructuring:

```
sales = data
  .map(({bookingId, "Total Paid": total)) => [bookingId, total])
  .filter(allNotNaN);
```

Answer (score 3):

map is meant to be 1:1.

If you also want filtering, you should `filter` and then `map`

```
sales = (
  data
  .filter(d => (!isNaN(+d.BookingID)&& !isNaN(+d["Total Paid"]))
  .map(d => [+d.BookingID,   +d["Total Paid"]]; 
});
```